# How to implement a function that normally returns a float, but can sometimes fail?

Tags: software-engineering, gdscript

In Godot GDScript, I have a function that returns a `float`.

Inside the body of the function, I use the built-in method `find`, that can return `-1` if nothing is found.

In that case, I could place a condition right before the loop and return the float `-1.0` (I can't return `null` and it looks like there aren't exceptions, nor optionals, nor other common things).

```
func get_my_float(c) -> float:
    
    var idx = p.find(c)
    
    for i in range(0, idx):
        
        //...

    return my_float
```

But: is there any other thing I can do?

Does it make any sense to return a `Variant`, instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in that you can't return `null`, which is because you have declared in your method that it returns a `float`. So, yes, removing the type declaration so it returns a variant is an option.

If you do this, remember that you should check `null`.

Be aware that operating with `null` will cause an error. But since this error happens when you try to use `null` it is away from the cause of the `null`. Which does not make for the most useful of errors.

*Also the Godot editor will show green line numbers on the lines that are type-safe, and show gray line numbers otherwise (i.e. using variant or unsafe casts), which is useful when reviewing your code.*

---

You could return `NAN` (not a number) which would allow you to keep the  `float` type. With a couple caveats:

- Consider if `NAN` might be a valid result in some cases.
- Remember that you need to check for `NAN`. And nothing is equal to `NAN`, in fact one of the ways to check if a variable is `NAN` is checking if it is different to itself, or you can use the more readable `is_nan(…)` method.

Similarly to `null`, the errors that come from `NAN` happen away from the cause. However operating with `NAN` will result in more `NAN`. Which is arguably worse that using `null`. Thus, if you can help it, **please don't use `NAN`.**

---

You are also correct that Godot does not have exceptions. You might, however, use `push_error` and return. Which leads to a question: why would you use `push_error`?

If you come from language that has exception, you might be familiar with the idea that some exceptions are intended to help the developer. For example "argument out of range" exceptions. You should not catch those exceptions. Instead, you should fix the code so they don't come up in runtime. However, you still want it to show during testing and debugging. And, of course, if some of them sneak into production, you want them to show up in logs.

You get that with `push_warning` and `push_error`. They will show up in the debugger, and also in logs. *And you cannot catch them like exceptions, because they aren't exceptions.*

You might also consider using `assert` for this purpose, or you can use the `breakpoint` keyword, given that those will interrupt in the debugger.

---

Option types and similar approaches has been proposed, but - at the time of writing - have not been implemented.

You *could* have a custom return type. For example you can define a nested class (add them at the bottom of the same file) with a `float` and a `bool`.

In Godot 3.x:

```
class OptionalFloat:
    var has_value:bool
    var value:float setget set_value

    func set_value(mod_value:float) -> void:
        value = mod_value
        has_value = true
```

In Godot 4:

```
class OptionalFloat:
    var has_value:bool
    var value:float:
        set (mod_value):
            value = mod_value
            has_value = true
```

And then use it like this:

```
func get_my_float(c) -> OptionalFloat:
    var result := OptionalFloat.new()
    var idx := p.find(c)
    if idx == -1:
        return result
    
    for i in range(0, idx):
        # …
        result.value = something
        # …

    return result
```

*The examples above do not handle the case where you try to consume the value without checking if there is any. You can define a getter alongside the setter to do that. And perhaps use `push_error` there.*

Be aware that these optional types would also require some kind of check (similar to checking for `null` or checking for `NAN`).

OK, you *could* do that. In particular if you really want to keep the type information. However, it is not a common approach. Instead people often fallback to variant, since it can represent a `float` (or whatever type) or `null`, also has some overhead, but you have to write less.

---

So Godot does not have out parameters. In fact, you cannot choose to pass by reference. But you can pass an array!

```
func get_my_float(c, result:Array = []) -> void:
    var idx := p.find(c)
    
    for i in range(0, idx):
        # …
        result.append(something)
        # …
```

Notice here that `result` is optional (it has a default value).

*In Godot 4 you could use a typed array (`Array[float]`).*

That is the approach that we would use if we need the return value, and also we need to have some additional optional output. *In fact, this approach is used in parts of Godot API.*

Ah, but in this case we have left the result as `void` here. So we could use the return value instead. That is, we might return an array (which could be empty for no result):

```
func get_my_float(c) -> Array:
    var result := []
    var idx := p.find(c)
    if idx == -1:
        return result
 
    for i in range(0, idx):
        # …
        result.append(something)
        # …

    return result
```

Here, since we are returning, we could use packed arrays. In Godot 3 you can use a `PoolRealArray`. And in Godot 4, the equivalent of the `PoolRealArray` is either `PackedFloat64Array` or `PackedFloat32Array` (in Godot 3 which one you get depended on whether or not you had a 64 bits build or 32 bits build). *And I point out we can use them when we are returning because these are value types.*

Be aware that this does not eludes a check either, since you would have to check if the array is empty.

---

You might be putting the effort in the wrong place. If you make your function take the index in a parameter, how to handle when the value is not found becomes a problem of the layer above… There you have better context and could pick an appropriate action. So the method at hand only needs to handle the "argument out of range" situation.

---

Speaking of appropriate actions. I don't know what you are doing, because I lack said better context… But given the method name, an option that comes to mind is set a fallback default result:

```
func get_my_float(c, fallback := 0.0) -> float:
    var idx := p.find(c)
    if idx == -1:
        return fallback
    
    for i in range(0, idx):
        # …

    return my_float
```

*Some examples of possible default values which might make sense depending on the context: `0.0`, `1.0`, `INF`, `-INF`, `NAN`.*

Alternatively, consider if you should think of a `get_or_add_my_float` method. Or something like that.

---

Another approach you might consider is to pass continuation callbacks.

Godot 4 has the `Callable` type, inline anonymous methods ("lambda"), and you can pass methods as `Callable` directly.

In Godot 3 you can use the `FuncRef` type and the `funcref` method to create them.

---

*You know better than me what the situation is. I have given you options, you decide.*

Comment: Stellar answer, thanks. The function is a fake one, I used it to explain the problem   :-)

Comment: I feel that returning Variant has not much sense, but I could be wrong

Comment: @LifeafterGuest I take it as a boarding feature. If you are not yet familiar with types, or if you come from a language that uses full dynamic typing, then you can start writing GDScript with variant and it will work. And afterwards you can start adding type information steadily on your code base. Which is in the spirit of separation of concerns. Besides, there are areas of Godot that still lack typing (notably dictionaries), so you might still need to use variant in some places. With all that said, I agree that it is better to avoid variant when we can.

Comment: Is returning NaN an option here? I expected to see that as one of the suggestions, but maybe there's a reason it's not available or inappropriate?

Comment: @DMGregory Sure, you could return `NAN`, I'll add it. I didn't consider `NAN` in particular, but I quickly discarding using some value to represent no value, because it might be one of the valid values (i.e. perhaps it should `NAN` in some valid cases).

Comment: i'm not familiar with gdscript but there is also another option if there are pointers/references available; the function takes a reference/pointer to the variable and returns a bool; if the function's conditions are met, the passed-in reference is modified to the output value, and `true` is returned, otherwise no modification is done and `false` is returned. the user calls the function in an `if` statement and uses the modified variable(s) if `if`'s check succeeds

Comment: @TheWrecker As I mention in the answer, you cannot choose to pass by reference. You can work around it by passing an `Array` which I also mention in the answer. Although I didn't propose the equivalent of the particular solution you suggest.

Comment: oh, got it! thanks :)

Comment: @Theraot "Remember that you need to check for NAN": I don't know if I got it well but with this kind of functions a check is often required after you call it because the "issue" you have inside the function is replicated outside

Comment: @LifeafterGuest Even with an option you would have something like that. I don't think having to check is the problem. With that said, I agree that both `NAN` and `null` are problematic, in that you get the error away from the cause. And I also agree that `NAN` worse in that you can do operations with it (which also give you `NAN`) and not notice, while trying to do operations with `null` would cause an error. Still, it is an option. One that I didn't include initially, and I'm only including with caveats. I'll include a "please don't do this", how about that?

Comment: @Theraot in a particular function I'm working on, NAN is perfect, that is, it is the kind of solution I was looking for, since it can't cause any kind of conflict. Before DMGregory suggestion I ended up using the array idea, testing for array emptiness and eventually getting the float as the first element of the array.